# Communication between the Options page and Background Page in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying out a simple Google Chrome extension, in which I need to communicate between the options page and the background page for getting/setting the options.

I have tried chrome.extension.sendRequest(..) and chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(..) but with no success!

Am I missing something? Or should I post my code?

Comment: Generally, it's a good idea to post your code, or a cut-down version that demonstrates the problem without anything extraneous. It's much easier for people to tell what's going wrong when they see the code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In you background.html, you could have something like this:

```
<html>
<script>
  settings = {
    get foo() {
      return localStorage['foo'];
    },
    set foo(val) {
      localStorage['foo'] = val;
    }
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Now in your options page, you can simply use [chrome.extensions.getBackgroundPage](http://developer.chrome.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getBackgroundPage). For example in options.html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
  var bkg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
  function saveOptions() {
    bkg.settings.foo = 'bar';
  }
  function restoreOptions() {
    document.getElementById('foo').value = bkg.settings.foo;
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="restoreOptions()"> 
  <form onsubmit="return false;">
    <input id="foo" type="text" />
    <button onclick="saveOptions();">Save</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Remember one thing, the dev guide is your best friend :)
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devguide

Answer (score 0):

yeah, that's not gonna work:

```
<!--
  - JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files: see our Content Security
  - Policy  http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html
 -->
```