# Chrome extension store

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

when building my Google Chrome extension, I run into a problem with storing it's settings. I have created a settings page which is opened in a tab after the user clicks browserAction icon. This pages has UI for setting up my extension and it can, for example, store the settings into localStore. But the background page of my extension, which is supposed to read these settings, doesn't have any localStore.

Where should I store the extension settings so it would be accessible from anywhere in the browser and stored "forever"?

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Actually, your background page is supposed to store the settings and read them out for various units requesting it. Even the configuration page must get/set the settings from the background page. May be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961544/communication-between-the-options-page-and-background-page-in-google-chrome can help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store data temporarly by using your backgroundpage:

```
// in your backgroundpage
// Set a value
window['yourvalue']=123;
// Get a value
alert(window['yourvalue']);

// in any other page (options/popup/message/whatever)
var bg=chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
// Set a value
bg['yourvalue']=123;
// Get a value
alert(bg['yourvalue']);
```

I always use these functions in my extensions:

```
var bg=chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
// Save data
function save(key, val) {
    bg[key]=val;
    var data={};
    var tmp=localStorage.getItem("MyPlugin");

    if(tmp!=null&&tmp.indexOf("{")>-1&&tmp.indexOf("}")>-1)
    {
        data=JSON.parse(tmp);
    }
    data[key]=val;
    localStorage.setItem("MyPlugin", JSON.stringify(data));
}

// Restore the data
var data={};
var tmp=localStorage.getItem("MyPlugin");

if(tmp!=null&&tmp.indexOf("{")>-1&&tmp.indexOf("}")>-1)
{
    data=JSON.parse(tmp);
    for (var key in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            bg[key]=data[key];
        }
    }
}
```